# Kotlin extension function on subsbcribing to RxJava's Flowable data

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java2, reactive

I want to write a function that automatically subsbcribes to RxJava's `Flowable<T>` and get the resulting data. This data will then be passed as an argument to another method that does the processing. I am struggling with Kotlin's extension function syntax and generics.

I want to convert this call:

```
    val scheduler = Schedulers.newThread()
    disposable.add(
        viewModel.getExams().subscribeOn(scheduler)
            .observeOn(scheduler)
            .subscribe({ exams ->
                exams.forEach { 
                    getSubjectOfExam(it, Schedulers.newThread())
                }
            }, { error ->
                Log.e(
                    "OverviewFragment",
                    "Unable to fetch list, $error"
                )
            })
    )
```

which is very lengthy in my `Activity` code, to a method that returns the data that I want to process.

In this case I'd like a list of exams (`List<Exam>`) passed into the argument of `getSubjectOfExam()`, which is the method for the list processing.

My function so far, which compiles but does not work at all:

```
/**
 * General subscription of items in a Flowable list
 * @param f method to be executed when list is loaded
 * @param scheduler scheduling units
 */
private fun Flowable<out List<Any>>.listSubscribe(
    f: (List<Any>) -> Unit,
    scheduler: Scheduler
) {
    disposable.add(
        this.subscribeOn(scheduler)
            .observeOn(scheduler)
            .subscribe({
                f(it)
            }, { error ->
                Log.e(
                    "OverviewFragment",
                    "Unable to fetch list, $error"
                )
            })
    )
}
```

it will be called like so:

```
    viewModel.getExams().listSubscribe({ resultData ->
        resultData.forEach {
            val exam = it as Exam
            getSubjectOfExam(exam, Schedulers.newThread())
        }
    }, Schedulers.newThread())
```

So yeah, I tried to make an extension function and passing a function as one of its arguments (called a higher-order function I believe).

With my method, the `getSubjectOfExam` doesn't get called at all. Is there something I'm missing?

I'll be subscribing to `Flowable`'s all the time in my Activity so this function will really help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your code and it seems it is working okay. Is there any chance that `viewModel.getExams()` or `getSubjectOfExam()` is not working?

Also I could suggest few optimizations:

```
protected fun <T> Flowable<out List<T>>.listSubscribe(
    f: (List<T>) -> Unit,
    scheduler: Scheduler
) {
    disposable.add(
        this.subscribeOn(scheduler)
            .observeOn(scheduler)
            .subscribe(f, { error ->
                Log.e(
                    "OverviewFragment",
                    "Unable to fetch list, $error"
                )
            })
    )
}
```

Then you won't need type conversion:

```
viewModel.getExams().listSubscribe({ resultData ->
    resultData.forEach {
        getSubjectOfExam(exam, Schedulers.newThread())
    }
}, Schedulers.newThread())
```

In fact you can replace `List<T>` with just `T` and make it work with any types. Also, observing and subscribing with same scheduler doesn't make a lot of sense to me. I think you can remove`.observeOn` completely and the code will still observe on the same scheduler you put in `.subscribeOn`

Comment: Thanks so much for the tips! After a few hours debugging, indeed I found that getExams() doesn't have anything in it yet, must be a bug in my insertExam method.